# C++ thread-per-request chat on linux with sockets and multiple clients

Tags: c++, sockets, pthreads

we are learning how to work with sockets and threads and are trying to make a simple chat program. Multiple clients can successfully connect and all of them can receive messages, but only the first connecting client can send messages.

So client nr 1 completely works, and all others can only receive but not send to the server.

All threads are running like we think they should, but only the first receiving thread is able to read from the receive queue.

with netstat we can see that the message queue of the second client is full
[screenshot from netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acjRE.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "socket.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int clients[100];//All Clientnumbers
int i=0;//Number of connected Clients
Socket* sockArray[100];
Socket* sockArray2[100];
queue<string> nachrichten;//message queue

void *empfangen(void* x);
void *tpr(void* servsockp);

int main()
{

    cout << "Hello, World! Server startet" << endl;

    ServerSocket servSock(6200, 1000);//start Serversocket
    ServerSocket *servsockp = &servSock;

    pthread_t tpr_starter;//new thread that creates tpr
    pthread_create(&tpr_starter, NULL, tpr,(void*)servsockp);

   while(true)      //if there are messages in the queue send them to all clients
    {
        if(nachrichten.size()!=0)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < i; y++)
            {
                try
                {
                    cout<< "Gesendet: " << nachrichten.front() <<clients[0]<<clients[1]<<i<< endl;
                    (*sockArray[y]).send(nachrichten.front());

                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    cout << e.getError() << endl;
                }
            }
            nachrichten.pop();
        }
    }
    pthread_join(tpr_starter, NULL);
}

void*tpr(void* servsockp)//open socket for every request, start new receiving thread
{
    while(true)
    {
        clients[i]= (*(ServerSocket*)(servsockp)).accept();
        int*x =new int(i);

        Socket *sock = new Socket(clients[i]);
        sockArray[i]=sock;
        sockArray2[i]=sock;
        i++;
        sleep(2);

        pthread_t rec;
        pthread_create (&rec, NULL, empfangen, (void*)x);
    }
}

void *empfangen(void* x)//listening on new socket, put received messages in queue
{
    int number=*(int*)x;
    cout <<"Receiving/thread started on Socket Nr: "<< number<<endl;
    while(true){
        try {
            string nachricht = (*sockArray2)[number].recv();
            if(nachricht=="")
            {
                break;
            }
            cout <<"Received: "<< nachricht << endl;
            nachrichten.push(nachricht);
        }catch(SocketException e){
            cout << e.getError()<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell if we are on the right way or if we are doing something completely wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what's inside your `ServerSocket` class but I assume it works similarly like the OS' sockets library. `accept()` should already return a new socket for a new connection, no need to do this: `Socket *sock = new Socket(clients[i]);` And also, `int*x =new int(i);`... What to say about this... you were probably programming something in Java, haven't you? It works but you have a memory leak, you never delete the `int` you allocated with `new`. You can't use `int i` like that, it's not thread safe. It needs to be `std::atomic<int> i;` and it should be used differently.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very basic c++ socket wrapper written from my professor for the normal C OS' sockets. I will look into what exactly happens after accept(). I am not sure what i was thinking as i programmed "int*x =new int(i);", but i was trying to somehow remember the socket number even if the loop starts over and deletes the local variables.

Comment: The int is nowadays 32 or 64 bit, but it's always of equal size or smaller than pointer. So you can cast the int directly into pointer and back into int in the thread function, no need for `new int` complication. It will be copied to the thread function so you don't need to care about the original `int`'s lifetime. Every `new` must have a corresponding `delete` otherwise the RAM is never freed.

Answer (score 0):

Today my professor found the solution:

```
(*sockArray2)[number].recv();
```

this line is absolutely wrong, it has to be

```
sockArray2[number]->recv();
```